# How do meta reputation and badges work?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, meta

Unlike Stack Overflow meta, I've noticed that here all my reputation points have been transferred over from the main site. But not badges.

Will my reputation be synced between the two? If so, why not the badges as well?

Comment: This is duplicated on the main meta: [Why are badges on per-site-metas separate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117523/why-are-badges-on-per-site-metas-separate)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All metas work the same except Stack Overflow, which is treated like a normal site in the network because it predates Stack Exchange's expansion into [many separate sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/). MSO has a problem where people who post ideas can often lose rep because the idea gets voted down, even though the post itself was well written. The [per-site metas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) avoid this problem by not having a notion of meta rep, or even meta accounts; it's just an extension of the parent site that keeps the meta posts separate from the actual Unix/Linux content. Since meta still has [privileges](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges) just like the main site, we still need rep of some kind, so we use the rep of the parent account.

So in short, reputation is synced because you need reputation to use privileges here. Badges  aren't synced because there's no reason for them to be; you don't need them for anything

Comment: Well, unless I'm blind, at present, when I get upvoted in a meta post (U&L meta in this case), I can't see my actual rep for meta. It will always show the rep for the U&L site instead in the headline. But neither will it *add* any rep to my U&L non-meta account. So at least at the moment, it seems that upvotes on a per-site meta have no visible effect at all.